# Runaround with trying to read mdf

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I am having trubble to get the stored values from my mdf. I can see they are there and all is working as suposed to untill i a want to get hold of them, I just cant. I have been trying for almost 48h and I just cant get it to work. I read tons of guides and other threads here but nothing seems to work for me. I guess I just have get my head around this way of accessing and mdf SQL database. I just want it to give up the secrets stored on specified row.

I am trying to access the three values stored on a numbered row(specified as int row) in a mdf file called Table1 and return them to the caller.

My code I have been fighting the last hours is this:

```
       public static void loadAnimalData(int row, out string stringId, out string name, out double age)
    {
        int antal = AnimalsDBCount();
        String connString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|path.to.db|DBList.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID WHERE ID = " + row, con))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                m_stringId = reader.GetString(0);    
                m_name = reader.GetString(1); 
                m_age = reader.GetDouble(2); 

            }
        }
        con.Close();
        stringId = m_stringId;
        name = m_name;
        age = m_age;

    }
```

I am lost here, I can't seem to get access to specied row or values, Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Well the first problem is you haven't named your table. `SELECT ID FROM [where???]` - next your `SELECT` list needs to name all of the columns you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Might you want is;</strike>

```
m_stringId = reader[0].ToString();    
m_name = reader[1].ToString();  
m_age = reader[2].ToString();
```

[`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) read *rows*, since you select one, you can't access others.

> Provides a way of reading a forward-only stream of rows from a SQL
>   Server database.

You shoudl select other columns also like;

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, NAME, AGE WHERE ID = " + row, con))
{

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       m_stringId = reader.GetInt32(0);   
       m_name = reader.GetString(1); 
       m_age = reader.GetString(2); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! I have started to understand how to collect items from a database alot more now. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You are only selecting the `ID` (which is already known), not any other columns.

Try changing:

```
"SELECT ID WHERE ID = " + row
```

to

```
"SELECT ID, NAME, AGE WHERE ID = " + row
```

Comment: I was missing this part! Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to select your columns in your select statement

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, name, age from TableOfInterest WHERE ID = " + row, con))
```

Then you can use them in your Reader

Comment: Yes, i missed to target the database and wich items to collect. Thanks for helping out here!! Saved me alot of time! Thanks!!